# How to deny all access to a directory and redirect 403?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder on my webserver and want to deny all access to that folder and all the files in it. Additionally, the visitor must be redirected to a specific error page on the same server.

The secured folder path is:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/some_folder/files
```

The error page is located here:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/some_folder/error.php
```

I tried placing a .htaccess file in the 'files' folder. This does prevent visitors from accessing the folder and files, but the redirect does not take place. I suspect that the syntax of the relative path is not correct.

This is my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /../error.php
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

When hitting the secured folder URL, the browser gives me this error message: "A 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Does someone have an example of what my .htacces should be?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in `some_folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine !^error\.php$ error.php [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite all requests that start with `/some_folder/` to `some_folder/error.php` though browser won't see status code `403`.

Inside `error.php` you may use this php code to return `403`:

```
http_response_code(403);
```

Comment: This does also prevent access to `some_folder` and not only the `files` directory. Still no redirect as well.